# Unlimited number of user inputs

Tags: java

I have an assignment to make a program which allows the user to enter an **unlimited**
set of numbers **until 0 is entered**, to print the smallest and largest number, and to say if they are odd or even.

I am comfortable with everything except on how to allow the user to enter as many numbers as desired and am unsure on how to start this. Should I be using loops or another method?

Please note I only began learning Java last week and so am **unfamilliar** with the language

Many thanks!

Comment: Loops are the way to go. Provide a special input sequence (e.g. ask the user if she wants to continue and if no end otherwise start the next iteration).

Comment: loops. but rather ask your professor/teacher what is meant with unlimited. If you don´t have condition to stop the loop you will have an infite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am comfortable with everything except on how to allow the user to enter as many numbers as desired and am unsure on how to start this. Should I be using loops or another method?

Since this is a homework, and you probably do not want us to do your homework for you. This is what you can do:

```
do{
    //prompt user for input
    //prompt user to continue (y/n)
    //if 'n' was given
        //proceed = false;
}while(proceed);
```

You can use a **do-while** or **while** loop. You can now prompt user for input infinitely till they decide to stop.

---

**Update 1: (According to changes in question)**

Terminating condition: when 0 is received as input:

```
do{
    //prompt user for integer input
    //if (input == 0)
        //break;   (exit loop)
    //store input
}while(input != 0);
```

Comment: Thanks I've just looked at the documentation for do while and it looks like it should work for this purpose, thanks

Comment: @Tom If you have more questions, you can leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

***Try to do it on your own.Use this for reference only.

I know its not right to give away the code as it is for your assignment.Just use (understand and learn)this if you didn't get the output.

```
        int n=0,temp=0,z=0,i=0,j=0;
        int []a=new int[1000]; //as size is not given by user assign the array with a much greater value

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //Object for BufferedReader class used for reading elements

        do{
            System.out.print("Enter the number:");
            a[n]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  //String to integer conversion
            n++;
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more numbers(0/1):");
            z=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }while(z!=0);


        //Sorting 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
            for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                if(a[i]>a[j])
                {    
                    temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }   
            }
        }  

        //Now after sorting the smallest number will be in the first location ie; 
        //"0" so inorder to check it is even or odd we take check its remainder when it is divided by 2.
        if(a[0]%2==0){
            System.out.println("The smallest number is : "+ a[0] + " & the number is even");}
        else{
            System.out.println("The smallest number is : "+ a[0] + " & the number is odd");}

        if(a[n-1]%2==0){
            System.out.println("The largest number is : "+ a[n-1] + " & the number is even");}
        else{
            System.out.println("The largest number is : "+ a[n-1] + " & the number is odd");}
```

A sample output is as  follows :

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: Thanks for giving such a comprehensive answer ! I must admit some of the concepts and items used are a bit beyond me at this point but this is a great learning tool for me so thankyou! :)